# How to get change between in time in two rows, and display as minutes and seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This sample script works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[15, '2','5/29/2019  9:59:30 PM'], [2, '3', '5/29/2019  7:30:06 PM'], [15, 'system', '5/29/2019  6:50:35 PM'], [2, '2', '5/29/2019  6:35:24 PM'],[10,'system','5/29/2019  6:27:43 PM']]


# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['floor','subject','time'])

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
print(df.dtypes)

df['time_delta'] = df['time'] - df['time'].shift(-1)

# print dataframe.
df
```

When I run this same code on my dataset, I get quite different results. I just exported everything t CSV, and this is what I see.

[image]

When I Googled this issue, I found this:

```
pd.to_timedelta((60*df_simulation['person_wait_time']).astype('int'), unit='s')
```

All I wan to do is have ColumnS show minutes and seconds

Comment: If you're expecting positive time differences then try `df['time_delta'] = df['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']`

Comment: If you want to convert to minutes do `df['time_delta'] = df['time_delta']/pd.Timedelta("1m")`

Comment: The second one worked. Thanks! One more question. What was wrong with this? 
df['time_delta'] = df['time'] - df['time'].shift(-1)
In my mall data sample, it works fine. In my actual real-world data, it gives nonsensical results.

Comment: I don't think anything wrong with it, negative timedeltas just display funny.  `-1 days +21:30:00` is the same as - 2.5hrs for example.  I.e. -1 day + 21.5 hours = -24 + 21.5 = -2.5 hours.

Comment: Oh, got. Thanks for sharing that with me!